# UIViewController multiple inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, multiple-inheritance

I have a class called `BaseViewController` which contains a function where I can add a header to my VC and anchor it

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    let headerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return view
    }()

    func addHeader() { 
        view.addSubview(headerView)
        // then anchor it to top
    }

}
```

I have another class called `ScrollViewController` which adds a scrollViewController to my VC and anchors it

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return view
    }()

    func addScrollView() { 
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        // then anchor it to top
    }

}
```

Finally my main class `HomeViewController` wants to have both a header and a scrollView so I inherit from both like this:

```
class HomeViewController: ScrollViewController, BaseViewController {

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addScrollView()
        addHeaderView()

        let view = UIView()
        //anchor view to bottom of the header
    }
}
```

However swift doesn't allow multiple inheritance so I tried using protocols and extensions which works but the problem is that I want other views to be able to be anchored to the header and scrollView so it didn't fit my needs.

What could I do so I can implement something like that

Thanks

Comment: The standard way to do this sort of thing in Swift is via protocol extensions. Why exactly did that not work for you? I'm having trouble parsing that sentence.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I edited my question and hopefully it makes more sense. I want to be able to have access to the `headerView` view so I can use it when I am anchoring other views to it

Comment: "I want to be able to have access to the headerView view so I can use it when I am anchoring other views to it" What does that have to do with the protocol? You have not shown _any_ attempt to solve the problem with protocols, so it's difficult to see why that's not the answer.

Comment: @matt If you could talk a look at @picciano 's answer down below you will see that he showed me the protocol implementation. Here is why it won't work in my case: In my `HomeViewController I want anchor a view to the bottom anchor of `headerView` but since I can't access `headerView` I will not be able to do that. Im sorry if it seems confusing but does that make a bit more sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift does not support multiple inheritance. However, protocols and protocol extensions can accomplish what you want.

Example:

```
protocol HeaderProtocol {
    func addHeaderView() -> UIView
}

extension HeaderProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func addHeaderView() -> UIView {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(headerView)
        // then anchor it to top

        return headerView
    }
}

protocol ScrollViewProtocol {
    func addScrollView() -> UIView
}

extension ScrollViewProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func addScrollView() -> UIView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        // then anchor it to top

        return scrollView
    }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ScrollViewProtocol, HeaderProtocol {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scrollView = addScrollView()
        let headerView = addHeaderView()
    }
}
```

Alternative approach:

```
protocol HeaderProtocol {
    var headerView: UIView? { get set }
    func addHeaderView() -> UIView
}

extension HeaderProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func addHeaderView() -> UIView {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(headerView)
        // then anchor it to top

        return headerView
    }
}

protocol ScrollViewProtocol {
    var scrollView: UIView? { get set }
    func addScrollView() -> UIView
}

extension ScrollViewProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func addScrollView() -> UIView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        // then anchor it to top

        return scrollView
    }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, ScrollViewProtocol, HeaderProtocol {
    var scrollView: UIView?
    var headerView: UIView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView = addScrollView()
        headerView = addHeaderView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Protocols wont work for me because I want to have access to `headerView` in my `HomeViewController` so I can use it to anchor other views to it. I updated my question, hopefully it makes a bit more sense

Comment: see update. alternatively, you can define the protocol to require that the implementation has the scrollView and headerView variables defined.